# NumPy Broadcast: Adding an ndarray across elements (a,b) in (M,A,B,N) shaped array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an array of images with rgb pixels, so the array has dimensions `(image_count,height,width,3)`

I am adjusting the individual pixels by a random amount I calculated on the side, of shape: `(image_count,3)`.

Right now, I have an interpreted loop to add the adjustment to the individual pixels.

---

How do I broadcast this addition so that, for each pixel, I do the following operation:

```
image_set[i,h,w,:] += pixel_adj[i,:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce new axes with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) at appropriate dimensions for `pixel_adj` to make it `4D`, just like `image_set` and then perform the summation adjustment to bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
image_set += pixel_adj[:,None,None,:]
```